# CKEditor 5 Register More Than One Upload Adapter

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I use CKEditor 5 to implement an editor to our software. I want to upload images and videos with this editor. It has image plugin. I customized ckfinder upload adapter to upload images to our server. It works perfect. I uploaded images and show them in the editor successfully. Then I wanted to upload video files to our server. So I created a video plugin for ckeditor to upload, display videos. Also I created another upload adapter to upload videos to our server. In this point, ckeditor filerepository plugin **accepted only one adapter**. Two adapter was imported but filerepository used last imported adapter. I want to use image upload adapter to upload images and video upload adapter to upload videos. But I can't figure it out.

Image upload adapter is initialized with this code:

```
init() {
    const url = this.editor.config.get( 'imgUpload.url' );

    if ( !url ) {
        return;
    }

    this.editor.plugins.get( FileRepository ).createUploadAdapter = loader => new ImgUploadAdapter( loader, url, this.editor.t );
}
```

Video upload adapter is initialized with this code:

```
init() {
    const url = this.editor.config.get( 'videoUpload.url' );

    if ( !url ) {
        return;
    }

    this.editor.plugins.get( FileRepository ).createUploadAdapter = loader => new VideoUploadAdapter( loader, url, this.editor.t );
}
```

How can I tell the filerepository to use image upload adapter for images and video upload adapter for videos seperately? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the `loader` param you get an instance of [`FileLoader`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-FileLoader.html) which exposes the native [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object in the [`FileLoader#file`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-FileLoader.html#member-file) property. That means that at this stage you can access the file name via:

```
this.editor.plugins.get( FileRepository ).createUploadAdapter = loader => {
    const fileName = loader.file.name;

    if ( fileName.endsWith( '.mov' ) ) {
        return new FileUploadAdapter( ... );
    } else {
        return new GenericUploadAdapter( ... );
    }
};
```

Comment: I run the code line which I mentioned when I initialize image upload adapter. Also init method of video upload adapter contains this code line. But in there, new UploadAdapter( ... ) creates a class instance different from image upload adapter. I mean, when I import two adapter plugins to ckeditor, each adapter plugin creates own adapter instances. But Filerepository uses last created adapter instance. I uploaded an image file and video upload adapter tried to upload image file. I don't want this.

Comment: I can solve this problem with using one adapter and this adapter needs to decide how to upload files by file type. But I want to seperate adapters. Each adapter should do its own job.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The code that you mentioned in your question is wrong. If you want to use different upload adapters for different files then you need to handle that in `createUploadAdapter()`.

Comment: I edited the question. Please, look the code snippets. When CKEditor initialize plugins, these init() methods are running. When I upload a file, upload() method of the last initialized plugin is running. Not its own upload() method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to assign just one callback. Exactly like in my answer. You can't modify `editor.plugins.get( FileRepository ).createUploadAdapter` twice! This way, only the latter callback will be executed. You need one plugin which knows about both adapters and assign just one callback. Exactly like in my answer.

Comment: this is not working for me. loader.file is a promise. so i can`t reach a name.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @Furkan Kara. I have the same probrem when using two upload adpter in ckeditor5. And ckeditor5 used the last imported adapter which I cannot control.